# Prestashop webservice 302 error from localhost

Tags: php, apache, web-services, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I follow prestashop tutorial, and I get a **302 found error** from the server.
The key is god, I have all permissions trough it.

Have you got ideas ?

```
// Here we define constants /!\ You need to replace this parameters
define('DEBUG', true);                                          // Debug mode
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://127.0.0.1/mystore/prestashop/');     // Root path of your PrestaShop store
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');   // Auth key (Get it in your Back Office)
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

// Here we make the WebService Call
try
{
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);

    // Here we set the option array for the Webservice : we want customers resources
    $opt['resource'] = 'customers';

    // Call
    $xml = $webService->get($opt);

    // Here we get the elements from children of customers markup "customer"
    $resources = $xml->customers->children();
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e)
{
    // Here we are dealing with errors
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
    else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
    else echo 'Other error';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code 302 is a redirect, and so is unlikely due to a certificate problem. My initial guess is that you need to add a / (or remove it) from your URL. Some http server frameworks will redirect when a resource does not end in a /, so, instead of:

```
GET /endPoint

Try

GET /endPoint/
```

The other possibility is that this resource requires authentication and the server is redirecting you to a login page. If you want to know what is going on (and not guess), take a look a the response headers for the 302. There will be a Location header telling you where the server wants you to go instead.